# Envoy lua filter - http call cluster invalid. Must be configured

Tags: filter, lua, google-kubernetes-engine, istio, envoyproxy

I am trying to create an envoy filter for all of my microservices deployed on a GKE cluster which is running istio.

In the filter I want to read 2 header values and send a request to an external service on web to get list of all groups that the user has authority of.

When I send the request I get "http call cluster invalid. Must be configured" error.

As per my understanding we need to register the host as cluster so that envoy understand where to send the request and I have added a value in "clusters" section of my filter.yaml file.

```
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
kind: EnvoyFilter
metadata:
  name: authorization-filter
  namespace: default
spec:
  filters:
  - listenerMatch:
      listenerType: SIDECAR_INBOUND
      listenerProtocol: HTTP
    filterName: envoy.lua
    filterType: HTTP
    filterConfig:
      inlineCode: |
        function envoy_on_request(request_handle)
          request_handle:logWarn("Inside filter")
          local token = request_handle:headers():get("Authorization")
          local partition = request_handle:headers():get("partition-id")
          if token == nil or partition == nil then
            request_handle:logErr("Token or Partition is empty")
            request_handle:respond({[":status"] = "400",["Content-Type"] = "application/json"}, "{\"ErrorMessage\":\"Bad Request: Authorization or Partition-Id missing in headers\"}")
          end
          request_handle:logWarn("Sending request")
          local headers, body = request_handle:httpCall(
            "lua_cluster",
            {
              [":method"] = "GET",
              [":authority"] = "example.com",
              [":path"] = "/api/authorization/groups",
              ["Authorization"] = token,
              ["partition-id"] = partition
            },
            nil,
            5000)
          request_handle:headers():add("authorization-response-headers", headers)
        end

  clusters:
  - name: lua_cluster
    connect_timeout: 0.5s
    type: strict_dns
    lb_policy: round_robin
    hosts:
    - socket_address:
        address: "example.com"
        port_value: 8888
```

What am i missing here?

Comment: Have you taken a look about the example of Istio Envoy here, just to compare your deployment with the example? https://istio.io/v1.4/docs/reference/config/networking/envoy-filter/

Comment: @blueboy1115 yes I followed the example given in docs, still it isn't working

Comment: As per your issue requires more advanced troubleshooting, I recommend you to contact Google Cloud Support, in order to provide them more detailed information from your project here https://console.cloud.google.com/support

Comment: Did you use "- applyTo : CLUSTER" as shown in the Istio EnvoyFilter examples?